# Show that two ideals are equal in $K=\mathbb{Q} (\theta)$ for $\theta$ a complex root of $x^3+x+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q} (\theta)$ for $\theta$ a complex root of $x^3+x+1$, and $R=\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ its ring of integers. Show that the ideals $(2+\theta,3)_R$ and $(1-\theta)_R$ are equal.

One direction is easy, since $1-\theta = -(2+\theta)+3$, so  $(2+\theta,3)_R\supseteq(1-\theta)_R$.

Comment: Prove that $3=(1-\theta)(\theta^2+\theta+2)$.

Comment: Complexity of $\theta$ is not an issue here: if $\theta'$ is the real root, $\Bbb Q(\theta)$ and $\Bbb Q(\theta')$ are isomorphic algebraic number fields.

Comment: True, it was used in an earlier part of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I=(2+\theta,3)_R$ and $J=(1-\theta)_R$. It's immediate that $J\subset I$ since $1-\theta = 3-( 2+\theta)$.

Moreover, we have $3=(1-\theta)(\theta^2+\theta+2) \in J$ and $2+\theta=3-(1-\theta) \in J$, so $I\subset J$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the norm  $N(\theta)=1$, from the constant term of the defining equation for $\theta$. Changing $x$ to $1-x$ in that equation we get the minimal polynomial for $1-\theta$ whose constant term is checked to be $3$ which belongs to the principal ideal generated by $1-\theta$ ( being the  product of the conjugates). Now one can proceed as in the answer given by chi trung chau.